# Website code is weird when scraped by Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api

Since this afternoon, Facebook is not able to read the og tags of a website I'm working on anymore. Facebook debugger says all my properties are missing (og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, etc) when I can clearly see all of them in my source code.

When I view the source of this page (or any other page on this domain), everything looks ok.

However, when I input that page in Facebook's debugger and use 'See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL', the code is all messed up with words and spaces missing. In fact, the whole section containing the og properties is missing.

What's happening? I haven't changed anything to the website recently and it was working fine before. Only thing that changed recently are my dns settings, but this should not be affecting Facebook...

Anyone sees what I'm missing here?
Many people suggested in other threads that the problem is because the paths are relatives instead of absolute (like for og:image, for exemple), but that clearly isn't my problem as my paths are absolute, and the section with all my og properties is simply just not showing up when scraping as Facebook.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the browsers auto fix some HTML for rendering the page correctly, things like closing tags, adding missing semantic tags, etc. But the bots are a bit more demanding on valid HTML.

Let's take the first 12 lines of the source of that page you shared. This is what the browser receives:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html
class="ie8" lang="fr-FR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html
class="ie9" lang="fr-FR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html
lang="fr-FR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <!--<![endif]--><head><link
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.vedettequebec.com/wp-content/cache/minify/ef20c.css?x41125" media="all" /><meta
charset="UTF-8" /><meta
name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><link
rel="pingback" href="http://vedettequebec.com/xmlrpc.php" /><meta
name="author" content="BadassB"><link
```

As you can see, the attributes are wrapped up to the next line, which is kind of valid and most browsers will handle that, but looks like the Facebook **scraper** trims the `\n` characters and interprets the code like so:

```
<!doctype html><!--[if IE 8]><htmlclass="ie8" lang="fr-FR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 9]><htmlclass="ie9" lang="fr-FR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><htmllang="fr-FR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <!--<![endif]--><head><linkrel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.vedettequebec.com/wp-content/cache/minify/ef20c.css?x41125" media="all" /><metacharset="UTF-8" /><metaname="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><linkrel="pingback" href="http://vedettequebec.com/xmlrpc.php" /><metaname="author" content="BadassB"><link
```

You see the issue now? The code is broken due to the attributes being added right next to the tag name, causing tons of "unclosed tags". For example, check the `<html>` tag being converted to `<htmlclass>` and its closing tag will be `</html>` because there's nothing right after the tag name, making that tag unclosed.

Disable any plugins that could be harming your HTML, plugins like HTML minifiers. Check in the settings if there's something like "wrap attributes to new lines".

Comment: I did see the problem that you are referring to, but I couldn't understand why it was doing it... In the end, it was indeed a problem with a minifier plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem on my websites too. It's because of W3 Total Cache's Minify feature. Disable it and purge all caches, then you're good to go.

Comment: That totally fixed it, thanks!The thing is, I have been using W3 Total Cache's Minify feature for more than a year, so why did it just now started to cause problems? I kept the same settings all this time.

Comment: Facebook may change their crawler recently.